# Update Distance Between Elements

Tags: javascript, distance

I have two elements, and one is moving towards the other. I am trying to get the new distance as it moves closer. Consider the code below:

```
<html>
    <center>
    <body onload = 'start()'>
    <div class='field'>



  <div id='bull'></div>
    <div id='mount'></div>
    </div>
    <button id='one'>DO</button>
    </body>
    </center>


<style>
.field{
    width: 440px;
    height: 260px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#bull{
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
#mount{
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgba(20, 10, 45);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 210px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function start() {
    var ball = document.getElementById('bull');
    var button = document.getElementById('one');
    var mount = document.getElementById('mount');
    button.addEventListener('click', go);

    var x_pos = 0;
    var y_pos = 0;
    var bounce_point = 200;
    var ball_dim = ball.getBoundingClientRect();
    var ball_h_half = ball_dim.width / 2;
    var ball_w_half = ball_dim.height / 2;

    var mount_dim = mount.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mount_h_half = mount_dim.width / 2;
    var mount_w_half = mount_dim.height / 2;

    function go() {
        for(x_pos = 0; bounce_point > x_pos; x_pos++) {
            ball.style.margin = x_pos + "px";
            ball.style.transition = x_pos/2 + "s";
            var dist = ((ball_h_half - mount_h_half)*(ball_w_half - mount_w_half)) + ((mount_h_half - ball_h_half)*(mount_w_half - ball_w_half));
            console.log(dist);
            if(dist < 3) {
                console.log('One');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When bull reaches comes within 3px of mount, nothing happens... I've pretty much explained the issue as best as I can.
**
When bull reaches comes within 3px of mount, nothing happens... I've pretty much explained the issue as best as I can.**

Comment: You should add a bit of HTML and CSS to this code, i gave it a try and i have no clue how the elements dimensioning relate to their relative distance; either your logic is a bit flawed, or it depends on a specific CSS that we don't know

Comment: Just added it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i tried a little bit more, and your logic doens't seem to fit to what you want to do. First of all, you probably noticed your value in the log doesn't change.

It could have been because the values are retreived outside the loop, but not only (they actually have to be in the loop to be updated). You have 2 other problems: first, you are measuring the elements width and height, which don't take account of margin or other positioning. Your elements don't change size, so the value also won't. The other problem is actually the transition itself on the movement. Because of the delay, all your loop iterations are most probably done, and the margin already set to its final value when your "bull" effectively starts to move. It means that in the loop, you can't detect the position change, the element having not started to move yet. Using the value that was just set (margin) instead of detecting the real position of the element should show a progression for the value, but it makes harder to detect the collision because your 2 elements don't have the same positioning rules and you can't just compare the margins.

Here is a quick example that gets updated values (because the transition has been disabled, if you enable back, the problem comes again). You'll notice your calculation for the collision is wrong too. You can't just compare a distance between 2 corners for that, for a rectangle it's rather "has gone beyond left vertical edge AND has gone beyond top horizontal edge" (this of course takes only in account the top left corner, to be complete, it should also be added that it must not have reached the right or bottom edge yet).

Well, I can't propose you an all ready solution, but this addresses your code main issues:

```html
<html>
    <center>
    <body onload = 'start()'>
    <div class='field'>



  <div id='bull'></div>
    <div id='mount'></div>
    </div>
    <button id='one'>DO</button>
    </body>
    </center>


<style>
.field{
    width: 440px;
    height: 260px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#bull{
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
#mount{
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgba(20, 10, 45);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 210px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function start() {
    var ball = document.getElementById('bull');
    var button = document.getElementById('one');
    var mount = document.getElementById('mount');
    button.addEventListener('click', go);

    var x_pos = 0;
    var y_pos = 0;
    var bounce_point = 200;
    var ball_dim, ball_x, ball_y, mount_dim, mount_x, mount_y, diff_x, diff_y;
    
    var stayInLoop = true;
    //ball.style.transition = "0.4s"; //i don't know why you updated the transition time based on position, changed to a fixed value outside the loop because it's quicker for the example
    
    function go() {
        for(x_pos = 0; bounce_point > x_pos && stayInLoop; x_pos++) {
            
            ball_dim = ball.getBoundingClientRect();
            ball_y = ball_dim.top + 10; // +10 because we're considering the bottom edge of bull
            ball_x = ball_dim.left + 15; // +15 because we're considering the right edge of bull

            mount_dim = mount.getBoundingClientRect();
            mount_y = mount_dim.top;
            mount_x = mount_dim.left;
            
            diff_x = mount_x - ball_x;
            diff_y = mount_y - ball_y;
            console.log(diff_x, diff_y);
            
            ball.style.margin = x_pos + "px";
            
            if(diff_x < 3 && diff_y < 3) {
                console.log('One');
                stayInLoop = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT/SUGGESTION**: i suggest looking at `window.requestAnimationFrame()` [MDN doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) for a better control on animations

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote the code a while ago and it worked... I was basing my work off another script...